# Why is `--human-readable` needed and not default?

Tags: command-line

Several command line tools use the `-h` or `--human-readable` option to print file size in a human readable format (i.e., `36G` vs `37550836`).

- Why is this option needed and not the default?
- Aren't these tools mainly for output to humans?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. Because they didn't exist originally, and the default behavior is backwards compatible. Also, because they don't exist on all unix variants, and the default behavior is compatible with other unix variants.
2. For many tools, because they are intended to be parseable by other tools. This is rarely the case for `ls`, but parsing the output of `du` or `df` is relatively common. (Mind, for `df`, you should use `df -P` when parsing.)
3. Because some humans prefer the 37550836 format, because when you see a bunch of such numbers, their relative size is visually clear (number of digits).

Comment: Especially 3) when I pipe the output straight through into `sort -n` because I'm less interested in quickly seeing the rough size of each directory and more in which subdirectory is taking up disproportionally too much space...

Comment: @Shadur Ah but sort takes a `-h` too!

Comment: I think 2 (e.g. for scripting) is the major reason.

Comment: @quodlibetor What OS/distro?  kubuntu lucid sort does not accept -h and I can see no equivalent.

Comment: @user23861 `sort -h` was introduced in GNU coreutils 7.5. Lucid has 7.4, so on Ubuntu you need at least maverick.

Answer (score 15):

Note that if you set BLOCKSIZE=human-readable in your environment, this will be the default, at least for the commands from GNU coreutils, i.e. if you're using bash put:

```
export BLOCKSIZE=human-readable
```

in your $HOME/.bashrc file.

Comment: Looks like `BLOCKSIZE=h` might be sufficient.  But great tip!

Comment: The [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size=human-readable) suggest `BLOCK_SIZE=human-readable`.  Also didn't know about support for thousands separators until I read that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on OSX

Comment: @jameslin: this might be a GNU coreutils specific variable. You could create an alias ...

Answer (score 6):

Beside what Gilles said:

When these tools where invented hdd was very small, compared with today. You didn't need help to read a number like 400000.

And if you don't like it, use the alias system. In your home directory,

```
edit ~/.bashrc
```

and insert, for example:

```
alias df='df -h'
alias du='du -h'
```

Note that in contrast to many other languages, you aren't allowed to have a blank before or behind the assignment operator (equal sign).